# Opencart how to test if module is assigned for a custom layout?

Tags: module, opencart

I have created a module and assigned that to custom layout (Route - product/category).
In this page i need to show only module contents.

So is there any way to do check if module is assigned to current layout ?

SOmething like below,

```
if ($current module = "Product_list") {
 // Dont display products
}
else {
 // Else display products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding this into the module code itself, you just need to check the current route

```
if(!empty($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'product/category') {
    ... Code ...
} else {
    ... Code ...
}
```

Comment: How about coding this into category page ?

Comment: On your category page itself the code above would always be true so there would be no point in having it